# How to use a DataSource based on condition being true?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm currently trying to build a query that uses a datasource based on a particular condition being true. Say "if value == 1, use datasource 1. If value == 2, use datasource 2.

These tables are already a couple of levels into my datasources.

Haven't been able to find info on this anywhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify the tables and relations, but using these datasources as an example:

- CustTable

  - CustTrans (JoinMode: ExistsJoin)
  - CustInvoiceJour (JoinMode: ExistsJoin)

Suppose you want to exists join on *either* `CustTrans` or `CustInvoiceJour`?

This can be accomplished by enabling and disabling the corresponding datasources:

```
custTable_ds.query().datasourceTable(tableNum(CustTrans)).enabled(!useInvoice);
custTable_ds.query().datasourceTable(tableNum(CustInvoiceJour )).enabled(useInvoice);
```

This should be done before `super()` in the `executeQuery` method of the `CustTable` datasource.